# Numpy Array Concatenation Multiplies array... why?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, concatenation

I have been desperately trying to figure out why an array concatenation leads to the array being multiplied by 2 on the first iteration...

This is my code:

```
def run(filename, max_iter = 1e6):
    data, fm = data_extraction(filename)

    large_output = None

    iteration_count = 0    

    while iteration_count < max_iter:
        iteration_count += 1
        print iteration_count
        results = calculations(data, (0.9,1.1))

        if large_output == None:
            large_output = results[:,1] #stores the energy array
            print large_output
        else:
            large_output = np.c_[ large_output, results[:,1]]
            #large_output = np.vstack([large_output, power_and_energy_var[:,1]])
            print large_output
```

and this is the console output for the print statement and 3 iterations only:

```
1
[  3.59891391e+01   5.75841568e+00   ]
2
[[  7.22402719e+01   3.62511328e+01]
 [  1.16726670e+01   5.91425129e+00]]
3
[[  7.22402719e+01   3.62511328e+01   3.70141435e+01]
 [  1.16726670e+01   5.91425129e+00   6.02176042e+00]]
```

As you can see `7.22402719e+01` is about twice `3.59891391e+01`, yet it doesn't occur for the successive iterations...

I have no idea why this is happening. I have tried everything I could possibly think off:

1) check what exactly was being executed using print statements
2) reloaded the kernel to erase any lingering variables
3) used np.vstack instead of np.c_ (same error)

Any help would be much welcome !!

Comment: `large_output = results[:,1]` is taking a view of part of `results`. If the array it's taking a view of gets changed, the view will reflect those changes. The concatenation (while slow, and a bad idea) probably has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: Aren't one of `large_output` or  `results[:,1]` empty at the first iteration? The output suggests the stacked array is 1D there and in succesives ones 2D.

Comment: @Divakar : no the large_output gets filled up during the first iteration as it is None. And the results are not empty.

Comment: @user2357112 : I'm not sure I understand the first part of your comment sorry. Would you mind explaining it again ? What alternative to the concatenation would you suggest ?

Comment: [Here's a quick intro to views and copies](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html), and as for the concatenation, the appropriate decision would depend on what your code is actually doing.

Comment: Making a list of subarrays and then building the final array in one call at the end is generally much more efficient than concatenating subarrays together one at a time, but depending on what you're really doing, there can be much more efficient solutions than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite all the very good comments and suggestions proposed in comments and answers, the answer was much simpler than that (it usually is when I spend a long time banging my head on the computer).

`large_output = results[:,1]`

should be explicitly expressed as an array:

`large_output = np.array(results[:,1])`

Answer (score 1):

Replicating your concatenation with a simple `results` array:

```
In [229]: results = np.arange(12).reshape(2,6)
In [230]: out = results[:,1]
In [231]: out = np.c_[out, results[:,2]]
In [232]: out = np.c_[out, results[:,3]]
In [233]: out
Out[233]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Even though the initial `out` is 1d, the subsequent ones simply concatenate columns

```
In [234]: results[:,1]
Out[234]: array([1, 7])
```

So any funny business between cnt 1 and 2 is the result of unknown behavior in `data` and `calculations`.  It's not a problem with the `np.c_` concatenation.

That said, the suggestion to build the list first is a good one

```
In [237]: out = []
In [238]: out.append(results[:,1])
In [239]: out.append(results[:,2])
In [240]: out.append(results[:,3])
In [241]: out
Out[241]: [array([1, 7]), array([2, 8]), array([3, 9])]
In [242]: np.array(out)
Out[242]: 
array([[1, 7],
       [2, 8],
       [3, 9]])
```

Though it probably won't bypass any funny business in creating `results`.